# Store loaded image as const in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm making an app in Expo / React Native and want to store the user's profile picture as a variable so I can load it once then pass it to different components as required - so I'm not loading the same image multiple times in different parts of the app. For images in my assets folder I can use the following line of code.

```
const userProfileImage = require('./assets/profilePicture.png');
```

I need the equivalent for images loaded from external sources - the equivalent of the following.

```
const userProfileImage = require('https://www.images.com/profilePicture.png');
```

N.B. I'm not sure passing JSX around or having a ProfileImage component really solves my problem. I literally just need the image asset as a variable if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

For network resources you can not use `require` in React Native, as far as I know. Instead you can use `uri`:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

Please refer to the documentation for further info: [Network Images](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#network-images)